# RadComboBox using templates

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a RadComboBox using  a checkbox and a label... Now you know how it shows the items being checked at the top, how it separates them by commas .. i.e

If the values are

```
[ ]Car
[ ]Bicyle
[ ]Trucks
```

As I select or check each.. it starts adding them like this..
`Car,Bicycle,Trucks` otherwise if nothing is picked it shows "`All Types`".

Well this is working fine but I am stuck when coming back to the page. When I come back to the page from some other page the RadComboBox has the items checked.. but the line where it is supposed to have

`Car, Bicycle, Trucks` does not show, it defaults to the first item "Car" and it does not show the whole string. This is pulling the values from a database and it is bringing the correct values as well as marking them check but.. How do I make it so that when I comeback that string is there in the combo box?

See examples at the telerik page for more info.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/templates/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, Just added a ddl.SelectedItem.Text = mystringVal;

and that was it.